# Doxygen: how to describe multiple parameters in one line?

Tags: doxygen

I have some functions that have many arguments, and sometimes those arguments are very similar in nature, for example when passing a color to a function i have the parameters "R G B", and I'd like to know if it's possible, in doxygen, to document those together. I do something quite extense for that right now:

```
    /// @param x      Initial cursor position at X axis.
    /// @param y      Initial cursor position at Y axis. 
    /// @param r      Text amount of red color (default: 1.f)
    /// @param g      Text amount of green color (default: 1.f)
    /// @param b      Text amount of blue color (default: 1.f)
```

I'd like to know if it's possible to unify parameters of the same nature, for example, is there a way I can do something similar to this?:

```
    /// @param x y :   Initial cursor position.
    /// @param r g b : Text color (default: white)
```

What would you recommend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I the documentation of the `\param` command it is stated:

> \param '['dir']'  { parameter description } Starts a
> parameter description for a function parameter with name
> , followed by a description of the parameter. The
> existence of the parameter is checked and a warning is given if the
> documentation of this (or any other) parameter is missing or not
> present in the function declaration or definition. The \param command
> has an optional attribute, dir, specifying the direction of the
> parameter. Possible values are "[in]", "[in,out]", and "[out]", note
> the [square] brackets in this description. When a parameter is both
> input and output, [in,out] is used as attribute. Here is an example
> for the function memcpy:

```
/*!
* Copies bytes from a source memory area to a destination memory area,
* where both areas may not overlap.
* @param[out] dest The memory area to copy to.
* @param[in] src The memory area to copy from.
* @param[in] n The number of bytes to copy
*/ void memcpy(void *dest, const void *src, size_t n);
```

> The parameter description is a paragraph with no special internal structure. All
> visual enhancement commands may be used inside the paragraph. Multiple
> adjacent \param commands will be joined into a single paragraph. Each
> parameter description will start on a new line. The \param description
> ends when a blank line or some other sectioning command is
> encountered. See section \fn for an example. Note that you can also
> document multiple parameters with a single \param command using a
> comma separated list. Here is an example:

```
/** Sets the position.
 * @param x,y,z Coordinates of the position in 3D space.
 */
void setPosition(double x,double y,double z,double t) { }
```

> Note that for PHP one can also specify the type (or types if you separate them
> with a pipe symbol) which are allowed for a parameter (as this is not
> part of the definition). The syntax is the same as for the
> phpDocumentor, i.e.
> `@param datatype1|datatype2 $paramname description`

So in this case:

```
/// @param x,y   Initial cursor position.
/// @param r,g,b Text amount of red, green, blue color (default: 1.f i.e. white)
```

Comment: Thank you very much Albert! That helped a lot. I actually tried this before, but my syntax highlight doesn't pickup anything after the comma, so I thought it didn't work. But now I see it is working indeed.

(ps: I think at the end you copied my example from the post which incorrectly uses the plural @params, so i recommend you edit that in case someone stumbles upon this post)

Comment: Oops you are right, didn't edit it enough.